# Analysis Integrable Function

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Define $f: [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, \text{if $x$ is rational}\\
0,\text{if $x$ is irrational.}
\end{cases}$$

$a.)$ Given any partition $P = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ of $[0,1]$, show that $U(f,P) > 1/2$.

$b.)$ For any $n\in \Bbb N$, let $P_n$ be the partition of $[0,1]$, be defined by $P_n =\{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n},\dots,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$ . Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} U(f,P_n) = 1/2$.

$c.)$ Show that $U(f) = 1/2$ and $L(f) = 0$, so that $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above function is a test for rationality.

For $i=1,2,...,n$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we define the following:

$m_i=inf\left\{f(x):x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]\right\}$

$M_i=sup\left\{f(x):x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\right\}$

Then it follows for some partition $P=\left\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\right\}$ on $[a,b]$, that

$$L(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^nm_i(x_i-x_{i-1}) \ \ \ and \ \ \ 
U(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^NM_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

Let's first consider part $b$)

When $x$ is rational, its mapping $x\to x$ has identical input and output values. Thus we can compare it to the function $g(x)=x$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

So, let $P_n=\left\{0,\frac 1n,\frac 2n,...,\frac {n-1}{n},1\right\}$ be a uniform partition on $[0,1]$, then we see:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}U(P_n,f)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac 1n\cdot \frac kn)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}\cdot \frac {n(n+1)}{2}=\frac 12$$

For part $a)$, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}U(P_n,f)$ is an infinitely partitioned sum, it then follows that any upper sum satisfies $U(P,f)>\frac 12$ (by part $b$).

Finally for part $c)$, we need only now consider the lowersum $L(P,f)$.

As noted above, for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, the function models that of the curve $y=x$.

We thus immediately see, any lower sum partitioned on $[0,1]$, yields a value of $0$. Another way to think about this is to note the irrationals cover the reals more densely than the rationales, thus forcing $L(P,f)=0$.

Thus finally we see, because $U(P,f)\neq L(P,f)$  for any partition $P$ on $[0,1]$, the Riemann integral must not exist.

In addition, here is another question that is very similar to your own that I also have answered, if you would like a slightly different explanation. [Find the upper and lower Riemann sums $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ for discontinuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220163/find-the-upper-and-lower-riemann-sums-uf-p-and-lf-p-for-discontinuous-fu/2220214#2220214)